# Why am I getting resource 404s on static nuxt.js app hosted on GitHub pages?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, github-pages, static-site

I have followed these steps:

1. Made a vue project with Nuxt.js (tested and working with `npm run dev`)
2. Used Nuxt.js static site generation to generate a static distribution under the `dist` directory of my `master` repository (also tested using VSCode's Live server plugin, works fine).
3. Deployed the `dist` directory to the `gh-pages` branch using: `gh-pages -d dist`
4. In the Options for my GitHub project, which is the GitHub Page for my user (`augusto-moura.github.io/`), I changed the Source to `gh-pages`.

[image: GitHub pages options]

The `gh-pages` branch seems to hold exactly what it's supposed to, but as I open the page, the scripts aren't loaded and each return a 404 eror.

[image: gh-pages branch]

[image: Errors on Network tab]

What am I doing wrong? GitHub seems to not be serving the JS files inside the `_nuxt` directory.

Comment: Are you following this guide? https://nuxtjs.org/faq/github-pages/

Comment: The guide in the docs seems oriented for project pages, not user pages. The `push-dir` method looks equivalent to using the `gh-pages` command.

Comment: Did you see this note at the top? _"Branch `gh-pages` for project repository OR branch `master` for user or organization site"_

Comment: @Phil yep, that was it! Post that as an anwser so I can select it. I'll keep developing the page in the `development` branch and change my deploy script to be: `push-dir --dir=dist --branch=master --force`. I wonder why GitHub allows me the option of what branch to use when only one of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the [How to deploy on GitHub Pages?](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/github-pages/) guide, in this tiny, easy-to-miss note...

> Branch `gh-pages` for project repository OR **branch `master` for user or organization site**

In order to use Pages for your user account, you need

```sh
push-dir --dir=dist --branch=master
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to add `.nojekyll` file at root dir when publishing to GitHub Pages, otherwise it won't get resource files from `_nuxt` dir.

Comment: I have added `.nojekyll`, as you can see here: https://github.com/augusto-moura/augusto-moura.github.io/tree/gh-pages . The resources are still not served.

Comment: This solved it for me. I added an empty `.nojekyll` file to the root directory on my `gh-pages` branch, and my JS assets are now resolving correctly.